# Want to create Component for DatePicker and TimePicker in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, bootstrap-datepicker, angular-components

I am working on angular application. I want to create a component for Date and Time. I want to give user flexibility to choose Date and Time Separately, but it should be stored in one variable. I am using Bootstrap v3.3.7  and AngularJS v1.5.8

The control will be looking like this
[image: The control will be looking like this]

The user should be able to load Date
[image: The user should be able to load Date]

Also use should be able to select Time
[image: Also use should be able to select Time]

Here is the link to [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/rM0aWJ61ifqqjlNIcPxJ?p=preview)

```
<div class="group row">
                                    <input class="textInput form-control pick_date datepicker_input" type="text" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YY">
                                    <div class="calendar_icon pull-right">
                                    </div>
                                    <input class="textInput form-control timepicker_input" type="text" name="time" placeholder="HH:MM">
                                    <label class="date_label_txt dropdown_labelTxt">
                                        Embargo
                                    </label>
                                    <span class="date_input_bar"></span>
                                    <span class="time_input_bar"></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>
```

Comment: Not sure exactly what the question is, where are you having trouble? If you're talking about Angular JS, you'd do this with directives. The controller for the directive would just have two event handlers, one for when the user picks the date (probably some kind of select or click method), and the other when the user picks the time. To save in one variable, either put both values in an object, { val2 : date, val2 : time }, or concatenate them together "the_date_the_time", or if you can, use a Date object.

Comment: do you have any example for it. I am able implement it for Datepicker. But now I want to give user option to choose date and time separately. I want to define it as common component, as it might be get reused in other pages. The value of date and time should be saved to only one variable.

Comment: I wouldn't be inclined to write all the code for it, what I'd have to suggest is that you read up on Angular JS directives. As soon as you do a couple of basic tutorials I think you'll see how to do it. But yeah writing all the code would be a little real work.

Comment: Thanks for your input @TimConsolazio I will read about it. Will get back to you if need any help. I was looking if any one has already done this kind of work already. Mean while I will try my own.

Comment: Oh there's a lot of people that have done this work, but the point here isn't to do the work but to provide you with pointers and info to help you do it :)

Comment: Thanks @TimConsolazio :)